# iTunesConnect GameCenter LeaderBoard new feature move to group

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, leaderboard

There is a new feature in game center, iTunes Connect.It says:

> To share leaderboards and achievements of this app with other apps you have provided, move this app to a Game Center group

My question is about datas. I have an app in app store. I will have another app too. If I use this share feature, will my first app leaderboard scores be deleted or do you know anything about this feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to review the free WWDC 2012 videos (go to [developer.apple.com]) and select the link for the WWDC 2012 videos.  There are various videos that will explain this new feature - I think the video you want was "Session 508 - What's New in Game Center".

The videos "Session 500 - Game Technologies Kickoff" and "Session 521 - Building Game Center Games for OS X" may also be of interest.
[1](https://developer.apple.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been answered in more detail here: [Game Center groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893545/game-center-groups?noredirect=1#comment54640536_30893545)

In short, your existing data won't get deleted. When you create the group or move an app into the group, you'll decided how the existing data is merged in.