# Game Center groups

Tags: ios, macos, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I have an iOS game with one Game Center leaderboard. I published the game a few months ago and now I'm working on the OSX version. I want to use the same leaderboard for both versions of the game, which means that I need to create a Game Center group. The problem is that Apple forces you to modify your leaderboard ID's when you move them into a group:

> Group ids must begin with grp.

Now, if I do that, I will need to update the iOS version of the game so that my users can keep posting their scores, and if I release an update for the iOS version of the game, players who don't install the update will no longer be able to use the leaderboard.

My question is: Is there a way to use the same leaderboard in both versions of the game without having to update the iOS version?

Thanks.

Comment: Or maybe I just don't understand how it works. Now that I think about it, it should work like this: -> old users post scores to my.leaderboard and see scores posted to my.leaderboard -> new users post scores to grp.my.leaderboard and see scores posted to both my.leaderboard and grp.my.leaderboard Is that how it works?

Comment: Ok, I uploaded a build for beta testing and the new (sandboxed) leaderboard is empty. That means that moving a leaderboard into a group deletes all previous scores. Can anyone confirm/refute this?

Comment: +Diego how did you go with this? Were you able to retain the player scores?

Comment: +Danoli3 I migrated to my game to GC groups, then submitted my game for OSX using the grp prefix. I didn't have to make any changes to the iOS version, it just worked. Game is called Arcane Tower in case you're interested.

Comment: Thanks +Diego. I was wondering if you have done an update since for the iOS version? Do you think you would have to update the iOS Version to include the grp. prefix if you did?

Comment: Now that I think about it I did update the iOS version with the grp prefix.

Comment: +Diego Yeah I figured that you definitely need the grp prefix! Curious though, Did you ever get this OSX game center bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295423/osx-game-center-couldnt-communicate-with-a-helper-application Any ideas since you are the only person I can find with a successful game center OSX game in the recent months :)

Comment: +Danoli3 I don't remember having seen that error. I'll take a look and if I find anything helpful I will let you know

Comment: +Diego I figured it out, needed this key in the entitlements com.apple.developer.game-center

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to update the iOS version. As you guessed already, the old IDs continue to work (under normal circumstances). If you add new leaderboards or achievements, they will be added to the grp.* though (necessitating an update if you want these to be picked up by the iOS version).

The sandboxed grp. leaderboard does not inherit the live scores from the iOS version, the old leaderboard scores for the live iOS version should be still intact.

The live grp. leaderboard *should* inherit the live scores from the non-group iOS version leaderboard.

In general, sandboxed leaderboards and achievements can get wiped from time to time, and it also takes some time (a couple of hours sometimes) for changes in your iTunes connect configuration to reflect properly in the sandboxed GC database for your app.